# How do I correctly choose two columns within Sub Selection Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Hello guys Im trying to use select within another Select and I get error of opperan should contain 1 value I saw other answers but coulndt figure out how to apply the solution. So here goes my query:

```
    SELECT a.date_insert AS date
    ,HOUR(a.date_insert) AS hour
    ,AVG(spood)
    ,AVG(factor)
    ,(SELECT AVG(dd.spood) as median_val1,AVG(dd.factor) as median_val2
FROM (
SELECT d.spood, d.factor, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM traf d, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE d.spood is NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY d.spood 
) as dd
WHERE dd.row_number IN ( FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2) ))
    
FROM traf a 
INNER JOIN mycolumn b
ON a.ref_id = b.ref_id where value_3 > 100
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Please any help would be grateful

** I get the error at the (SELECT AVG) which is the subquery **
opperand should contain 1 column while I wish to retrieve 2 columns

Comment: Move this subquery to FROM with proper joining condition.

Comment: For future reference, ALWAY show us ALL the error message. Do not summarise it. Invariably there is useful info in the parts people dont show

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.  You have a subquery in the `SELECT` clause, which is a *scalar* subquery:

```
 (SELECT AVG(dd.spood) as median_val1,AVG(dd.factor) as median_val2
FROM (SELECT d.spood, d.factor, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
      FROM traf d, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
      WHERE d.spood is NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY d.spood 
     ) as dd
  WHERE dd.row_number IN ( FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2
 )
```

A scalar subquery can only return one column and at most one row.  The simple solution is to return only one value in the subquery.  If you need multiple values, use multiple subqueries.

It is probably possible to rewrite your overall query.  However, your question doesn't provide sample data, desired results, or an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.

**-- Update**

Try using the `LEFT JOIN` with sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT a.date_insert AS date
    ,HOUR(a.date_insert) AS hour
    ,AVG(spood)
    ,AVG(factor)
    ,MAX(AVG_VIEW.median_val1) -- usgae of the values from sub-query
    ,MAX(AVG_VIEW.median_val1) -- usgae of the values from sub-query
FROM traf a 
INNER JOIN mycolumn b
ON a.ref_id = b.ref_id
-- added this
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(dd.spood) as median_val1,AVG(dd.factor) as median_val2
FROM (
SELECT d.spood, d.factor, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM traf d, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE d.spood is NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY d.spood 
) as dd
WHERE dd.row_number IN ( FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2) )) AS AVG_VIEW
ON 1=1 -- use proper conditions and accordingly use the correct columns in SELECT of this sub-query
-- till here
where value_3 > 100
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Note: You need to change this query little bit according to your requirement.

Comment: Im trying to retrieve the median of 2 columns by hour for a specific Day. So can I just copy paste the same code and put 1 column at a time?

Comment: @NewtonNick . . . You can do that.  However, there might be better solutions.  For that, you should ask a new question, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting two expressions from the sub-query which is in the `SELECT` clause.

If you are using sub-query in the `SELECT` clause, It must have only one value in sub-query's `SELECT` clause and must return only one row.

Try to remove one expression from the sub-query and you will find success.

Comment: When I remove one the sql query is infinite and never stops any idea of why is that? Also if I want to retrieve another column should I just reuse the subquery? like copy paste it?

Comment: Yes, You can do copy-paste. and the better option will be to join with sub-query and I don't understand why it executes for an infinite time. with two expressions, It was not taking the time and with one expression is it taking the time. Strange!!

Comment: With two expressions gets error should contain 1 opperand column. While with 1 expression is infinite loop.... Dunno